# coq syntax of theorem implication

Tags: coq

I follow this tutorial : https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html
Section 'Proof by Rewritting' :
The code

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m : nat,
  n = m =>
  n + n = m + m.
```

Produces the error :
Syntax error: '.' expected after [vernac:gallina] (in [vernac_aux]).
I don't get what am I doing wrong ?
Also, what is the best place to get documentation ? I mean, beginner-friendly documentation.

Comment: You need to replace `=>` with `->`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 1):

To use the text as it's written on the page you linked, you need to import some notations. In particular, `∀` and `→` don't exist by default. To import these notations use `Require Import Utf8.`

```
Require Import Utf8.

Theorem plus_id_example : ∀n m:nat,
  n = m →
  n + n = m + m.
```

The ASCII equivalents of these notations are `forall` for `∀` (as you figured out) and `->` for `→`. If you have the notations imported, you can see what they stand for using `Locate`. `Locate "→".` will have output

```
Notation
"x → y" := forall _ : x, y : type_scope
(default interpretation)
```

Of course, this doesn't give us `->`, since `->` is itself a notation for the same thing. Coq will display that notation by default, so if you input

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m : nat,
  forall _ : n = m,
  n + n = m + m.
```

(without `Utf8` imported), the output is

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
forall n m : nat, n = m -> n + n = m + m
```

which uses the `->` notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation